# JQuery Validate Plugin MS MVC: Won't validate

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm trying out the jQuery Validation plugin
[jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21)
Here is the markup of my form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("action", "contoller", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sxform" })){%>

    <div id="manifest">
        Manifest Option:<br />
        <%= Html.DropDownList("docid", ViewData["manifests"] as SelectList, new { @class = "required" })%>
    </div>
    <div id="release">
        Release Version:<br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("release", null, new { @class = "required" })%>
    </div>
    <div id="locale">
        Localization:<br />
        <%= Html.DropDownList("localization", ViewData["localizations"] as SelectList, new { @class = "required" })%>
    </div>
    <div id="label">
        Label:<br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("label", null, new { @class = "required" })%>
    </div>
    <div id="session">
        Session ID (optional):<br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("sessionInput", null, new { @class = "required" })%>
    </div>
    <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Build" /></div>    

<% } %>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sxform").validate();
});
```

I am using MS MVC HTML Helpers to render this form. The resulting markup looks fine. IE each input and selection element contains the attribute 'class' with the value 'required'.

When I submit this form the validation does noting. Can someone familiar with this library help? It looks pretty widely used.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this exactly, but just out of curiosity, why not use Data Annotations with Jquery client side validation? It does all the hard work for you. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine and should work. Make sure you have included the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Also look for possible javascript errors in the FireBug console.

Comment: I am sure that the plugin is included. I even hit a break point in my script that contains that rules. The post still occurs and no markup is added to my form to indicate that an input has been left null..